# Why is waitpid(-1, &status, 0) not suspending the process without any childs at all?

Tags: c, waitpid

I don't understand the waitpid() function very well. The manual says:

`The  wait() system call suspends execution of the calling process until one of its children terminates.  The call wait(&status)  is  equivalent to: waitpid(-1, &status, 0);`

Source: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/man2/wait.2.html

As far as I understand this: If I have a process and *no child process* what so ever and call the `waitpid(-1, &status, 0)` function then the process should hang there and don't continue because there can never be a state change without children and so the process just hangs there waiting for the child process to change state which will never happen in this case, but this understanding seems to be wrong because the code below does not hang at the waitpid() function. Instead it returns -1 for error which is plausible because there was no child process whatsoever *but as my understanding according to the manual goes the program should just hang at/in the waitpid() function* and wait for a child to change state. Yet there is no child, so there is no status change, so it should just hang in the waitpid() function and wait and wait. The below code should never reach the printf() statement but instead it does reach the printf() function.

This code is just for demonstrations puposes:

```
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int status;
  pid_t pid;
  pid = waitpid(-1, &status, 0);
  printf("%i\n", (int) pid); // pid returns -1
  return 0;
}
```

This program executes until the end but to my understanding according to the manual it shouldn't. What's wrong with my above reasoning?

Comment: No children so the statement does not hold - therefore does not need to hang.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly, the intention is that, by returning -1, it is indicating that there are no children to wait for (in a sense, all children *have* terminated).

Comment: I see. That's what I suspected anyway but I could not extract that information from the manual. So I wanted to find out programmatically.

Comment: The [manual](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/wait.html) says so in the section *Return Value* along with the section *Errors*.

Answer (score 0):

Check `errno` to find out why waitpid returned -1:

> **ECHILD** (for wait()) The calling process does not have any  unwaited-for
>                children.
>
> **ECHILD** (for  waitpid()  or  waitid())  The  process  specified  by  pid
>              (waitpid()) or idtype and id (waitid()) does not exist or is not
>              a  child of the calling process.  (This can happen for one's own
>              child if the action for SIGCHLD is set to SIG_IGN.  See also the
>              Linux Notes section about threads.)
>
> **EINTR**  WNOHANG  was  not  set  and an unblocked signal or a SIGCHLD was
>              caught; see signal(7).
>
> **EINVAL** The options argument was invalid.

Comment: It tells me that there are "No child processes". I kind of expected that.